# Is there anything wrong with the CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS as below to create my radio button, but it always give me a radio button overlapped with the label. I run it against Chrome and Safari. Anything wrong with my code below? Thanks.

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<style type="text/css">
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url("Images/background.png") -60px top no-repeat;
}
input[type="radio"]:hover + label:hover span:hover {
  background: url("Images/background.png") -75px top no-repeat;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background: url("Images/background.png") -90px top no-repeat;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:hover + label:hover span:hover {
  background: url("Images/background.png") -105px top no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="Data" value="agree"/>
<label for="radio-1" class="radio">
<span>Yes</span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apparently there *is* something wrong; or you wouldn't be asking. Anyway, these sorts of questions usually go best with an accompanying http://jsfiddle.net test-case.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried it on jsfiddle.net. Looks like it customizes the label instead of the radio button. What I expect is hover, checked on the radio button shows different background image. I guess the HTMl part is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha i did it its the `input:{display:none}` does the problem check otut..http://jsbin.com/OGoVoJI/1/edit

Comment: I'm trying to customize different images for the radio button (checked, hover, etc) by CSS rather than the label. I something wrong in HTML...